# PostgreSQL select specific items from JSONB array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
orders

order_number   products
1234           [{"upc":2434354, "title":"Widget"}]
4321           [{"upc":6434556, "title":"Shorts"}, {"upc":54346, title: "Shirt"}]
```

I want to generate an output like this

```
[
{order_number: 1234, upc: 2434354},
{order_number: 4321, upc: 6434556}
]
```

As you can see I pull out the UPC from the array (targeting the first element in the array only).

Note that `products` if of type `jsonb`

I tried this:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(products)[0]->>upc FROM orders ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10
```

But it gives a syntax error, I'm not sure exactly how to do array traversal in PostgreSQL

Also there is the possibility that `products` may be an empty array `[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=226a0bd43214a1e152d9bbf5e8cab9d2)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(
         jsonb_build_object(
             'order_number', order_number, 
             'upc', products -> 0 -> 'upc'
         )
    )
FROM
    orders
```

1. `products -> 0 -> 'upc'` gets the `upc` value of the first array element
2. `jsonb_build_object()` builds one JSON object per record containing the `order_number` and `upc` value
3. `jsonb_agg()` aggregates these JSON objects into one JSON array